# Javascript setInterval() creates a weird outcome(?)

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I encountered a weird problem with the setInterval method that I really don't get.

So I created a website with 25 boxes and the idea was that clicking on any box would change the backgroundColor of that box for half a second after which it would return to the original color. After that animation finished the next box would change its color for half a second and then go back to the original state. This cycle would continue until it reached the last box.

The code I wrote for that is this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i].onclick = starter;
    }
}

function starter(eo) {
    var box = eo.target;
    var counter = eo.target.id;
    box.style.backgroundColor = "#1A237E";
    setTimeout(cont, 500, counter);
}

function cont(counter) {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    box[counter].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    counter++;
    box[counter].style.backgroundColor = "#1A237E";
    if (counter < box.length) {
        setInterval(cont, 500, counter);
    }
}
```

(All the boxes have the class "box" and are labelled with IDs from 0 to 24)
The code actually executes and is technically working. The weird thing is that after about 8 iterations several boxes start to flash up simultaneously(different boxes for each iteration of the cont() function) and the whole code slows down enormously. This happens regardless of the starting position.

I have no idea where I made a mistake in the code, can someone explain to me white it happens?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: where in your code are you clearing the interval?

Comment: Are you clearing the interval once done?

Comment: As the previous comments alude to, you should be using setTimeout() instead of setInterval().